# Using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap doesnt always work

Tags: android

So I'm using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap to scale and display in an imageview files that i have saved locally from my android application. It seemed like it was working perfectly, Yet now it seems that for some reason only certain files are able to be scaled and others it crashes. When i try with what seems like larger files or maybe resolutions it breaks the code and my app crashes. Is there a reason for this or way to avoid it? or even a better way to scale files? Any advice would be great, let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post the stack trace that accompanies your crash whenever you're looking for help. But it sounds like you're running out of memory. Be sure to call Bitmap.recycle() on the current image before loading another one.

Comment: I understand that, what would it mean if it crashes on the first image that is opened?

Comment: Your first image is too big then. You can decode it in a different resolution (and therefore not have to load the original and then call createScaledBitmap() on it) using the BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize field. Set it to 2 for half scale, 3 for third scale, etc. Experiment with the Options class for your particular situation and problem.

Comment: So if quality isn't a huge concern should i load all the original images at say 1/3 scale and then work with them from there so i wouldn't have to worry about the user choosing an image too large?